# Ensure HTTPS binding exists in IIS' Default Web Site in Wix

Tags: c#, iis, wix

How can I ensure HTTPS binding exists in IIS' Default Web Site? I have tried doing that using C# Custom Action, which just checks existence using Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager class, but it requires admin permissions. It's not ok for me because I need to check that on pushbutton click, so I can't mark my customaction as deffered(I've tried and got an error)

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure HTTPs binding in iis Site Binding.

1.Select Default Web Site in the Connections and click Bindings... in the Actions pane.

2.Click Add... to add your new SSL binding to the site.

3.Select https in the Type drop-down list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for the way to do it from wix, during installation, automatically

Comment: Do you want to configure HTTPS for IIS website by WiX setup? if so, you can refer to this link: [Configure HTTPS for IIS website by WiX setup](https://mcpride.github.io/posts/development/2018/03/20/configure-https-for-iis-website-by-wix/).